# What this means and how to reverse it?

Tags: windows, bash, host

```
@echo off
SET hosts=%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
attrib -r %hosts%
echo. >>%hosts%
FOR %%A IN (

bs.studycoder.com

) DO (
 echo 1.2.3.4 %%A >>%hosts%
)
attrib +r %hosts%
echo Successfully added entries
```

Answer (score 0):

It blocks access to `bs.studycoder.com` by pointing it to a bad IP address (`1.2.3.4`). See this [Wikipedia article about the `hosts` file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) for details. It first removes the read-only attribute and at the end adds the attribute again, and it uses a list of sites to block, although the list only has this one entry.

To undo it, delete `1.2.3.4 bs.studycoder.com` from your hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`). You have to open notepad as **admin**, then open the file in it and change it there. You may also have to remove the read-only attribute on this file on Windows Explorer first.

Comment: As said: "it uses a list of sites to block, although the list only has this one entry"